# John the ripper doesn't show the passwords on cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd

recently i've been trying to crack the windows user account password and have extracted the LM and NTLM hashes from SAM file in C:\Windows\System32\config to a txt file hashadmin.txt using pwdump8.

Opened cmd and directed to the directory where john the ripper is installed and used the following command:

> john --format=LM d:\hashadmin.txt

it does the job but the password doesn't appear. its almost as if its null
heres the screenshot
[cmd jtr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czjIY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voSdJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this flag :

```
--show
```

Answer (score 0):

Append --show at your command or enter --show --format=LM